# Action Buttons css style in JavaFX ControlFX dialog

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, controlsfx

I've been using ControlsFX  dialogs to show information, but the style of my application is not blue, and does not match dialog style (color, borders) is there a way to change the button color or styles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note*

In a more recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417140/styling-default-javafx-dialogs), this time regarding the new `Dialog` API bundled with JDK8u40 early releases, I came with a less hacky and more clean solution, using stylesheets instead of inline styles and lookups.

So I'm updating this question, as `openjfx-dialogs` is still the way to have dialogs for the official releases 8u20, 8u25 and 8u31.

*New solution*

To customize the default style of a dialog with our own css file, we need to take into consideration that the dialog is in fact a new stage, with a new scene, and the root node is a `DialogPane` instance.

So once we have some dialog instance:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText("This is a Custom Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setContentText("We override the style classes of the dialog");
    ...
}
```

we can access to its dialog pane and add our own style sheet:

```
DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(
   getClass().getResource("myDialogs.css").toExternalForm());
```

In order to define our rules we need to know the descriptors already used. For that, we just need to look for `dialog.css` file in the `openjfx-dialogs.jar` (under the package com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.modena), or go to the source code at the [repository](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs).

Now we need to provide our custom rules to override the default ones for `dialog` and `alert` class selectors. The following rules will have the exact same effect as the inline styiling from my first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26811135/3956070).

```
.dialog > .dialog-pane {
    -fx-background-color: greenyellow;
}

.dialog > .dialog-pane > .button-bar {
    -fx-font-size: 24px;
    -fx-background-color: indianred;
    -fx-font-family: "Andalus";
}

.dialog > .dialog-pane > .content.label {
    -fx-font-size: 16px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold; 
    -fx-fill: blue;
}

.dialog:header > .dialog-pane .header-panel {
    -fx-background-color: cadetblue;
    -fx-font-style: italic;
}

.alert.confirmation.dialog-pane {
    -fx-graphic: url("lock24.png");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you don't provide the version you are using, I'll go with the new OpenJFX-Dialogs project ([source](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs/overview), started since 8.20.7 [version](http://fxexperience.com/2014/09/announcing-controlsfx-8-20-7/)), which are by the way the same dialogs we'll have with JDK8u40.

Firts, let's add some alert dialog:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText("This is a Regular Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setContentText("This is the message");

    Button button = new Button("Click to display an alert");
    button.setOnAction(e->{
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        result.ifPresent(System.out::println);
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(button), 300, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image: Regular Alert Dialog]

Now, to style this dialog, we need an instance of `DialogPane`, which is the root node within a dialog, where the header, the content and the buttons are displayed.

Via lookups or via `getChildren()` it's easy to find these components.

This is an example of customizing all of the components of the dialog:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText("This is a Custom Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setContentText("We override the style classes of dialog.css");

    Button button = new Button("Click to display an alert");
    button.setOnAction(e->{
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        result.ifPresent(System.out::println);
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(button), 300, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
// root
    dialogPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: greenyellow;");

// 1. Grid
    // remove style to customize header
    dialogPane.getStyleClass().remove("alert");

    GridPane grid = (GridPane)dialogPane.lookup(".header-panel"); 
    grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cadetblue; "
            + "-fx-font-style: italic;");

    // custom icon
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(new ImageView(
            new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("lock24.png"))));
    stackPane.setPrefSize(24, 24);
    stackPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    dialogPane.setGraphic(stackPane);

// 2. ContentText with just a Label
    dialogPane.lookup(".content.label").setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16px; "
            + "-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-fill: blue;");

// 3- ButtonBar
    ButtonBar buttonBar = (ButtonBar)alert.getDialogPane().lookup(".button-bar");
    buttonBar.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24px;"
            + "-fx-background-color: indianred;");
    buttonBar.getButtons().forEach(b->b.setStyle("-fx-font-family: \"Andalus\";"));

}
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image: Custom Alert Dialog]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getStylesheets().add("css_name.css");
```

https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs/src/7273358fd294d486b4959f0c89b24b76c49bec89/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/dialog.css?at=default

Comment: While it may be a basically a link only answer it does include a significant line of code and I actually prefer this answer to the accepted one.  I wish I could retract my downvote.

Comment: @jewelsea This was also the solution I gave on a recent [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417140/styling-default-javafx-dialogs) related to dialogs in JDK8u40. Do you want me to edit this answer and add this?

Comment: I'd prefer a new answer to this question José which demonstrates styling of ControlsFX dialogs using stylesheets in the same way that your answer to the recent question demonstrated styling built-in JavaFX dialogs.  I think sample solutions that demonstrate how to style dialogs are better if they use stylesheets rather than inline setStyle calls and lookups.