# Styling a dialog from JavaFX Openjfx Dialogs project

Tags: java, css, javafx, controlsfx

I was reading this question: [Action Buttons css style in JavaFX ControlFX dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808261/action-buttons-css-style-in-javafx-controlfx-dialog), to find out whether it's possible to change JavaFX alert dialogs in terms of style.

The answer was pretty good but I was wondering whether it's possible to just format certain words in the dialog?

For example, I just want one word to be underlined, I can't figure out how to do so though, because there is just one `.content.label` and the JavaFX `Text` class does not work properly with dialogs (if I'm not wrong).

Below is the code piece how the entire `Alert` dialog got modified.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
alert.setHeaderText("This is a Custom Confirmation Dialog");
alert.setContentText("We override the style classes of dialog.css");

Button button = new Button("Click to display an alert");
button.setOnAction(e->{
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    result.ifPresent(System.out::println);
});

Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(button), 300, 200);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();

dialogPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: greenyellow;");


dialogPane.getStyleClass().remove("alert");

GridPane grid = (GridPane)dialogPane.lookup(".header-panel"); 
grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cadetblue; "
        + "-fx-font-style: italic;");


StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(new ImageView(
        new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("lock24.png"))));
stackPane.setPrefSize(24, 24);
stackPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
dialogPane.setGraphic(stackPane);

dialogPane.lookup(".content.label").setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16px; "
        + "-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-fill: blue;");

ButtonBar buttonBar = (ButtonBar)alert.getDialogPane().lookup(".button-bar");
buttonBar.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24px;"
        + "-fx-background-color: indianred;");
buttonBar.getButtons().forEach(b->b.setStyle("-fx-font-family: \"Andalus\";"));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look at `DialogPane` class, you'll see that by default it uses a `Label` for the content. But also you have this:

```
/**
 * Assign dialog content. Any Node can be used
 * 
 * @param content
 *            dialog's content
 */
public final void setContent(Node content) {
    this.content.setValue(content);
}
```

So all you need to do is provide your custom node for the content:

```
Text text1=new Text("This is ");
text1.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16px; -fx-fill: blue;");
Text text2=new Text("underlined ");
text2.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16px; -fx-fill: blue; -fx-underline: true;");
Text text3=new Text("text");
text3.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16px; -fx-fill: blue;");

TextFlow flow = new TextFlow(text1,text2,text3);

dialogPane.setContent(flow);
```

and you'll have your dialog:

[image: Dialog]