# Styling default JavaFX Dialogs

Tags: javafx, dialog, javafx-8

I'm looking for a way to style the default JavaFX Dialog (`javafx.scene.control.Dialog`).

I tried to get the DialogPane and add a stylesheet, but it covers only a small piece of the dialog. I would prefer to style only with an external css file and without to add styleClasses over the code. This would look messy (header, content, own content on the content and more..)

I googled already alot and only found examples for ControlsFX, but since jdk8_40 JavaFX has it's own Dialogs i use them now.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

Since José Pereda posted the solution i created my own dialog.css.
I'll post it here because it covers the whole dialog and maybe someone want's to copy&paste it. Note .dialog-pane is already a given styleClass name so you don't need to apply your own. Of course, Josés is more fine detailed.

```
.dialog-pane {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.dialog-pane .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.dialog-pane:header .header-panel {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.dialog-pane:header .header-panel .label {
    -fx-font-style: italic;
    -fx-font-size: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can style your dialogs with your own css file, but for that you need to take into consideration that the dialog is in fact a new stage, with a new scene, and the root node is a `DialogPane` instance.

So once you create some dialog instance:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText("This is a Custom Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setContentText("We override the style classes of the dialog");
    ...
}
```

you can access to its dialog pane and add your own style sheet and your own class selector:

```
DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(
   getClass().getResource("myDialogs.css").toExternalForm());
dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("myDialog");
```

Now the trick is knowing all the rules a `Dialog` style sheet has implemented by default.

And that's a difficult task... since they are not in the `modena.css` file, as for all the regular controls. On the contrary, they are found in the `modena.bss` file, a binary file located in the jfxrt.jar under private packages.

After some digging I've managed to get those rules, so your custom `myDialogs.css` file will look something like this:

```
.myDialog{
    -fx-background-color: #f9d900;
}
.myDialog > *.button-bar > *.container{
    -fx-background-color: #a9e200;
}
.myDialog > *.label.content{
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
.myDialog:header *.header-panel{
    -fx-background-color: #a59c31;
}
.myDialog:header *.header-panel *.label{
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-style: italic;
    -fx-fill: #292929;
}
```

And you will have your styled dialog:

[image: Styled dialog]

<del>Note that being a bss file under private packages, these selectors can change without notice in future releases.</del>

**EDIT**

I've just found that the `.dialog-pane` selector is already part of [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/6cc08ec1ea82/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) in the last 8u40 [early versions](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html), so you can find all the selectors and rules applied to the dialog pane there.

Comment: I've just edited my answer, as modena.css already includes the `.dialog-pane` selector in the latest 8u40 ea. My other post was related to [openjfx-dialogs](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs),  the inbetween project extracted from ControlsFX, valid for 8u20, 8u25 and 8u31 versions.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it was very helpful! However, I have noticed that using `:header` is not working anymore, so I just used `.myDialog .header-panel`, which works perfectly. I am also using 8u40..