# JavaFX or controlsfx custom title bar

Tags: java, css, javafx, titlebar, controlsfx

Curretly, I'm using javafx.scene.control.Alert and org.controlsfx.control.Notifications for displaying messages to user.
I already have some dialogs with custom title bar so I want to have the same title bar on dialogs, but I didn't find any resources to style these two. 
Do I have to make my own dialogs?

Comment: Did you check the modena.css?

Comment: What Puce means is, have you checked the [JavaFX CSS-Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)?

Comment: Of course I did, I've found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417140/styling-default-javafx-dialogs but it doesn't concern the title bar..