# Customize JavaFx Alert with css

Tags: java, css, javafx

Searching in **caspian.css** I found that I can customize dialog-pane.Alert extends Dialog so I tried some of of these lines of code:

```
.dialog-pane {
   -fx-background-color: black;
   -fx-padding: 0;
    .....
  }

 .dialog-pane > .expandable-content {
     -fx-padding: 0.666em; /* 8px */
    .....
  }

.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container {
    -fx-padding: 0.833em; /* 10px */
    .....
  }

.....
```

but nothing changes.

**Question:**
How can I do that? I mean I want to customize the background, the buttons, the header and everything other.

Comment: `caspian.css` hasn't been the default stylesheet for JavaFX for years, you should use [`modena.css`](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/) instead.

Comment: @Jewelsea i see that it has the the same things as caspian, i mean the css selectors etc which doesn't work.

Comment: How have you added the stylesheet?

Comment: @fabian Yes.It is supposed this piece of code to work properly with Alert?

Comment: @José Pereda amazing... that is the answer thanks!!I hadn't understand that the Alert is a different stage so it needs to add stylesheet manually.

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for help i found answer on that...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417140/styling-default-javafx-dialogs/28421229#28421229) how to add **stylesheet** or|and **styleclass** to DialogPane,so you can add your costume css file.

**Example(picture + css code)**:

[image]

```
 .dialog-pane{
  -fx-border-color:black;
  -fx-border-width:2.0px;
 }

/**Costumization of The Bar where the buttons are located**/
.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container {
  -fx-background-color:black;
}

.dialog-pane > .content.label {
   -fx-padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
   -fx-background-color: yellow;
   -fx-text-fill:black;
   -fx-font-size:15.0px;
}

/**Costumization of DialogPane Header**/
.dialog-pane:header .header-panel {
  -fx-background-color: black;
}

.dialog-pane:header .header-panel .label{
  -fx-background-color: yellow;
  -fx-background-radius:10px;
  -fx-text-fill:black;
  -fx-font-size:15.0px;
}


/**Costumization of Buttons**/
.dialog-pane .button{
   -fx-background-color:black;
   -fx-text-fill:white;
   -fx-wrap-text: true;
   -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box, yellow, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   -fx-cursor:hand;
 }

.dialog-pane .button:hover{     
  -fx-background-color:white;
  -fx-text-fill:black;
  -fx-font-weight:bold; 
 }
```