# Is there a way to set the font on an Alert button?

Tags: javafx

I am looking for a way to set a specific font for the javafx.scene.control.Alert "OK" button for AlertType = WARNING. Does anyone know whether this is possible and, if so, how this is done?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can get access to the button via `DialogPane#lookupButton(ButtonType)` to set the font programmatically. Or you could use CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Slaw wrote in his comment there is a [`lookupButton` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DialogPane.html#lookupButton-javafx.scene.control.ButtonType-) available:

> This method provides a way in which developers may retrieve the actual
> Node for a given ButtonType (assuming it is part of the button
> types list).

So you can simply use it like this to set a new font:

```java
alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).setStyle("-fx-font-family: Vijaya;");
```

or you can do:

```java
((Button) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK))
                    .setFont(new Font("Vijaya", 12));
```

***Edit (answer to a question in the comment section):***

If you want to use a dedicated css file, you can do it like this:

```java
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();

// because the alert is a new stage, you have to reference the style sheet you want to use:
dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(App.class.getResource("alerts.css").toExternalForm());

// find the button and give it an id:
Button okBtn = (Button) dialogPane.lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
okBtn.setId("ok-btn");
```

**alerts.css:**

```css
#ok-btn {
    -fx-font-family: Vijaya;
}
```

If you want to style not only the button, you can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28421229/13561971).

Comment: Again, excellent! Works perfect. I didn't know that about the Alert being in a new stage. Interesting. Anko, Slaw, thank you so much! I've learned a lot. :-)

Comment: Thank for response :) 

What about the ContentText and the HeaderText ? is it possible to change the default Font ?