# JavaFX dialog title color customization

Tags: javafx-8

I have customize the Dialog popup using [This Link](http://codereply.com/answer/8ona63/styling-dialog-javafx-openjfx-dialogs-project.html)
But i can't able to change the title color please see the image below.

[image]

And is it possible to add a CSS to this popup, and how to custimize the ok button design alone? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28507525) and add

```
.dialog-pane:header .header-panel .label {
    -fx-font-size: 1.167em; /* 14px */
    -fx-wrap-text: true;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

to the css file.

> ... and how to custimize the ok button design alone?

One way can be to lookup the OK button then apply your custom css styles

```
Button button = ( Button ) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton( ButtonType.OK );
button.getStyleClass().add( "my-ok-button" );
```

Comment: how to customize the OK button design alone?