# buttons size increase controlsfx

Tags: java, javafx-2, controlsfx

is possible increase the size of the buttons in dialog.
[image]

I need to be bigger.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by accessing the ButtonBar of the dialog you created and then customize the buttons in it.

First get the ButtonBar instance:

```
ButtonBar buttonBar = (ButtonBar)yourDialogInstance.getDialogPane().lookup(".button-bar");
```

Then get all buttons applied to the dialog pane and set the style for them via a string containing css. For example:

```
buttonBar.getButtons().forEach(b->b.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18px;"));
```

A lot more detail: [Customizing Dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808261/action-buttons-css-style-in-javafx-controlfx-dialog)

Comment: Thanks grahan, but so sending buttons Actions.OK, to this Actions is possible change style?? thanks.

Comment: No Problem :) I am sorry, but i do not understand your new question complety. You want to change the style of these buttons with actions like clicking on other buttons of your program?